# Flutter combining text theme and direct styles

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, themes

I'm writing a Material app and want to use the predefined text theme styles as much as possible rather than re-inventing typical theme elements from scratch.

So to set the text a little bigger I do this

```
Text('foo', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge);
```

Which seems cool. But if I want it *emphasized*, there's no "bodyEmphasized" so
maybe I do this

```
Text('foo', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
```

But what if I want the text both bodyLarge *and* emphasized. There's certainly
no bodyLargeEmphasized, so I tried
to do this

```
Text('foo', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
```

But this throws a null safety error because apparently bodyLarge is nullable. Huh? How could standard text theme styles be nullable?

So what do I do? Is there a simple way to make something bigger and emphasized while staying within a standard theme styles? Maybe there is a logical theme that has a set of styles like bigger and bolder that can be safely combined? If not, what's a reasonably efficient way to handle this? Do I have to code a backup plan for bodyLarge being null, and any other style element I use? If I need to do that, I might as well create my theme from scratch. Or do I just append the shriek to bodyLarge! and hope for the best?

Comment: try `Text('foo', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);`

Comment: So @ShashikumarS you suggest "append the shriek and  hope for the best". I know I can do that. But WHY am I guaranteed that bodyLarge isn't null? Somebody made it nullable for a reason, didn't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this statement in the source code:

```
assert(
      (displayLarge == null && displayMedium == null && displaySmall == null && headlineMedium == null &&
          headlineSmall == null && titleLarge == null && titleMedium == null && titleSmall == null &&
          bodyLarge == null && bodyMedium == null && bodySmall == null && labelLarge == null && labelSmall == null) ||
      (headline1 == null && headline2 == null && headline3 == null && headline4 == null &&
          headline5 == null && headline6 == null && subtitle1 == null && subtitle2 == null &&
          bodyText1 == null && bodyText2 == null && caption == null && button == null && overline == null),
      'Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor.'
    );
```

These styles are nullable because either 2018 or 2021 styles are initialized. If you use the default 2021 styles, you can safely assume that bodyLarge property is not null. Otherwise this assert statement is going to fail when you try to run your code in emulator.

Comment: I see. So at this moment in time, it's safe to put the bang on bodyLarge, but at some future date, maybe, an exception that appears? Hmmm...

Comment: I hope it's the opposite - at some time the deprecated styles are removed, and the remaining styles won't be nullable anymore.

Comment: An optimistic thought, @Andrei, although it appears that didn't happen last time. In seriousness, to me the whole point of using a basic default theme is its stability over time, with new enhancements preserving the integrity of the past. I mean, for almost 30 years I could use <big><b>text</b></big> without a null object exception -- even if CSS may now redefine <big> and <b> to be something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

To make a text both bold and Italic you can use the flutter TextStyle class.

First you can put the text that you want in the Text widget :

```
Text('foo')
```

And then inside the Text widget add a style along with the following properties:

```
Text('foo' , style:
TextStyle(fontWeight :FontWeight.bold,
          fontStyle : FontStyle.italic,
),)
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. You are just using TextStyle. You aren't accessing the Theme styles. My question was how to combine direct TextStyles with Theme.of(context) styles.

Comment: you want to make the text bold and emphasized right?

Comment: No, I wanted to make it bodyLarge and emphasized.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
Text('foo', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: How does this address the null safety issue?